# Number of unique combinations of an 8 character string with 4 instances of two unique characters each

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assume you have an 8 character long string that is made up of 4 instances of 2 unique characters (ie 4 "a"'s and 4 "b"'s). How would you go about calculating the number of unique 8 character combinations that can be made (ie {aaaabbbb}, {aaababbb}, ..., {bbbbaaaa})?

The magnitude of unique characters is 72 (26 uppercase, 26 lowercase, 10 digits, and 10 special characters).

My assumption for accounting for the different unique characters is `72 x 71 x |unique combinations|` because the first character can be any from the pool of 72 and the second can be any from the pool except for the first one. Is this assumption correct and how would you find the number of possible unique combinations?

Answer (score 1):

The number of two-character combinations is not $72\cdot71$, but $$\frac{72\cdot71}{2}$$.  You have counted every combination twice, because picking 'a' and 'b' is the same as picking 'b' and 'a'.  There are $$\frac{8!}{4!4!}=70$$ $8$-character combinations from $4$ copies of each of $2$ letters.  If we have $4$ 'a's and $4$ 'b's there are $8!$ ways of arranging the letters if we regard them all as distinct.  (Imagine that the $4$ 'a's come in $4$ different colors, and likewise for the 'b's.)  However,. they aren't really distinct, so we have counted each arrangement of 'a's $4!$ times, and the same for the 'b's, which accounts for the division.

In all, there are $$\frac{72\cdot71\cdot70}{2}=178,920$$ strings.

Comment: So is this solved using the permutation formula P(n,k) (n!/(n-k)!) or is this some other formula like the closed permutation formula (n!/((n-k)!*k!)). The answer you proved lines up with a closed form permutation but I want to make sure Im not seeing connections that arent actually there. Also thank you so much!